# GROUP BY ID followed by parent_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to figure out how to order Customer records by `id` except for when `parent_id` (which lives on the customers table as well) is equal to the id of a parent record.

Desired order:

[image]

and so on....

Using raw sql, Postgres DB. No luck so far!

Comment: Add the original data, then the desired result.

Comment: How deep i the hierarchy? Is it only ever one level deep (i.e. only one parent) or could it go further (i.e. a parent could also have a parent)?

Comment: parent can not have a parent

Comment: That's easy then, and I think the accepted answer is good for what you need. If you had deep hierarchies, you'd need to use [CTEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a case statement to determine conditional ordering:

```
SELECT id, parent_id
FROM customers
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN id ELSE parent_id END, id
```

Comment: This is the right logic, but I think `coalesce()` is a better solution.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks, didn't know I could do a case in an ORDER BY